# Ionic: element outside of card

Tags: ionic2

How can I place button outside of card in Ionic 2?
Like this:

[image: Example Image]

I tried to use paddings, but no result.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using a negative margin like this

```
margin-top:-8px
```